# How we can get the .apk (Andriod) file using Axios call

Tags: javascript, axios, download, apk

Details ......

#### Steps:

> 1. I created the Axios call for hitting the backend server's request.
> 2. I just used responseType: 'blob', and received the response.
> 3. Its downloading is fine but causing issues while installing.
> 4. its shows there was a problem parsing the package

```
`axios({
  url: 'http://localhost:5000/static/test.apk',
  method: 'GET',
  responseType: 'blob', // important
}).then((response) => {
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(response.data));
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = url;
  link.setAttribute('download', 'test.apk');
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
});`
```

> **I want to check, whether I'm doing the correct way to get the.apk file from the server or if there are any other ways to download, If anyone has any ideas, could you help with this**

Comment: I don't know whether this will fix the broken apk issue but all you need is `location = 'http://localhost:5000/static/test.apk'`; This will trigger a download if an attachment is served.

Comment: Thanks, Chris. Actually, due to security issues, we should pass the token to the server to download the file, but the location doesn't token example:
location.href = "https://www.w3schools.com";

Comment: True, but please remove the backlink to w3schools. Also check the filesize, and whether the problem isn't in test.apk in the first place.